# Access an unmapped field in Symfony2 Controller

Tags: forms, symfony

I am creating forms with an unmapped field as explained in the [form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#mapped).

However when in the controller or similar I want to access it, currently I am using the POST request array and getting out from there like so:

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->request->get('my_form_name');
$unmappedField = $postData['unmapped_field']
```

I just can't help but thinking this is not the best way, and I cannot find anything on the official documentation.

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: What about calling get('unmapped_field') on your request Object?

Comment: Is this unmapped field contained into an Entity Object, or is your form binded to a flat array?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can access unmapped field in form

```
$unmappedField = $form['unmapped_field']->getData();
```

Comment: yes, yes, but how to get it dynmically in a scenario where i create dynamic unmapped fields

Comment: If you have a form with nested types, it'll be something like `$unmappedField = $form['subtype_name']['unmapped_field']->getData();`

Comment: you can use: $all = $form->all() ... then iterate over all and for each field: $field->getConfig()->getOptions()['mapped'] ... then you can decided which field to process depending on this option ...

Answer (score 16):

taken from the symfony doc sf 2.5 (also tested with sf 2.3):

form type:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('task')
        ->add('dueDate', null, array('mapped' => false))


  ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

controller:

```
$form->get('dueDate')->getData();
$form->get('dueDate')->setData(new \DateTime());
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes (scroll down a little bit)

Comment: I didn't know that `getData` had a `setData` complement.  Exactly what I needed, thanks!